# Difference in behavior in range selection (material-calendarview)

Tags: java, android, calendar

Also, I opened an issue for lib [here](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/issues/651).

I need to make implementation of range date selection so I found this lib suitable [link](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview).

But It really disturbs me. The issue in behavior range selection:

Case:

1) So, will say you need to choose dates from 1.09 to 5.09 (there is no problem) and then try to click on first(1.09) or last(05.09) date in selection. All selected days goes to unselected (and it is right behavior).

video : https://youtu.be/bprcy1IBpy4

2) So, will say you need to chose dates with in one day difference from 1.09 to 03.09(there is no problem) and than try to click on first(1.09) or last(3.09) date in selection. You are again will get range of selection (but without selected date). Example : click 1.09 than 3.09, than click again 03.09 and now you see range of selection from 1.09 to 2.09( it is really unexpected result) .

video : https://youtu.be/rN70_HTbvUA

I tried to clone the matirial-calendarview project and manage it, but I am not so strong to understood how does it work.

If you have any question feel free to ask.

So question : how to manage this lib to present one stable behavior? I prefer so, if I have selected range of dates and click to first or last day in selection so all dates goes to unselect.

Comment: So what it does in the end, is it selects range with open end, while you want it to select range with closed end?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov added video in question

Comment: Ah, so range behavior is different depending on how many dates are inside the date range (depending on range span), with edge case being 2 and 3 dates in range span. This does appear to be a bug in MaterialCalendarView implementation (jugding by [this line](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView.java#L1436), where it checks size of selection). You should monitor the github issue you've created.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes it is exactly the same that I found out, but I tried to dug deeper and understood how does this array size depend of . But it is complicate for me

Comment: They use array size as a state machine, and upon selecting range of dates they mark all dates inside that range as selected. This breaks in case you've described.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov ok, do you have idea how to fix?

Comment: To me it looks like it is just changing the range when you click on any selected day.

Only deselecting the date or dates towards the other end including the date you click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this code block ([link to source file in github](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/60a8cdb523bc2fc09e5a712ac7a5de7d02b08d88/library/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView.java#L1434))

When we select two days in calendar, then this means that we are selecting day range's start date and end date. This code block, which is meant for range selection is executed

```
} else if (adapter.getSelectedDates().size() == 2) {
    final List<CalendarDay> dates = adapter.getSelectedDates();
    if (dates.get(0).isAfter(dates.get(1))) {
        dispatchOnRangeSelected(dates.get(1), dates.get(0));
    } else {
        dispatchOnRangeSelected(dates.get(0), dates.get(1));
    }
}
```

When we select a range, for instance the range consisting of the 2,3,4,5 days, then the list of selected days has size of 4. When we click on the date to deselect range, then this day is removed from the selected days list before list is cleared, and now list contains 3 elements. In result this code block is executed, which is meant for clearing selected range

```
if (adapter.getSelectedDates().size() > 2) {
    adapter.clearSelections();
    adapter.setDateSelected(date, nowSelected);  //  re-set because adapter has been cleared
    dispatchOnDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
```

Everything works fine, if range consists of 4 and more days. When range consists of 2 or 3 days, then on "deselect range" size of the selected dates becomes 1 or 2 respectively (size - 1 because date clicked in selected range is removed prior to deselecting range), and range is not cleared, because condition

```
if (adapter.getSelectedDates().size() > 2) {
```

is not met.
To fix this, you could check if selection or deselection is happening and execute correct logic. My quick fix is

```
  case SELECTION_MODE_RANGE: {
        adapter.setDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
        if (adapter.getSelectedDates().size() > 2) {
            adapter.clearSelections();
            adapter.setDateSelected(date, nowSelected);  //  re-set because adapter has been cleared
            dispatchOnDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
        } else if (adapter.getSelectedDates().size() == 2) {
            final List<CalendarDay> dates = adapter.getSelectedDates();
            if (nowSelected) { // when selecting
                if (dates.get(0).isAfter(dates.get(1))) {
                    dispatchOnRangeSelected(dates.get(1), dates.get(0));
                } else {
                    dispatchOnRangeSelected(dates.get(0), dates.get(1));
                }
            } else { // in case range initially consisted of 3 dates, and now deselection happens
                adapter.clearSelections();
                adapter.setDateSelected(date, nowSelected);  //  re-set because adapter has been cleared
                dispatchOnDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
            }
        } else {
            if (nowSelected) {
                adapter.setDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
                dispatchOnDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
            } else { // in case range initially consisted of 2 dates, and now deselection happens
                adapter.clearSelections();
                adapter.setDateSelected(date, nowSelected);  //  re-set because adapter has been cleared
                dispatchOnDateSelected(date, nowSelected);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

I assume from debugger output, that nowSelected variable tells if selection or deselection is happening.